# Segmentation fault with strncpy

Tags: c

EDIT: Variable names

I'm making a linked list, and when I try to free a node it gives me an error. I tracked my code and found that my error is rooted when I create a node with this code.

The weird part is that if I assign one char less than what I want it to be it works. Also, it works fine for assigning "word", the issue lays in "id".

```
struct node* makeNewNode (char* word, char* id, int occurrences) {
    //make space for the new node
    struct node* temp = malloc (sizeof(struct node*));

    temp->word = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(word) + 1);
    strncpy(temp->word, word, strlen(word));
    temp->word[strlen(word)] = '\0';


    temp->id = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(id) + 1);
    strncpy(temp->id, id, strlen(id));
    temp->id[strlen(id)] = '\0';

    //assign the number of occurrences to the argument passed in
    temp->occurrences = occurrences;

    //return the newly created node
    return temp;

}
```

The struct for the node is:

```
struct node {
        char* word;
        char* id;
        int occurrences;
        struct node* next;
};
```

What I mean by one less is that this works:

```
strncpy(temp->id, id, strlen(id)-1);
```

However it means that I am losing one char consistently.

I've tried to manually copy the string with a for loop but it also doesn't work. I've tried appending one '\0' char but it also doesn't work.

If needed I can provide what I'm using to test this

Comment: (1) You should allocate memory space for the struct width; however, when you add a start at the very end, it allocates a pointer width only (i.e., remove the star at the very end of this line `struct llnode* newNode = malloc (sizeof(struct llnode))`) and (2) your code does not assign `newNode->next`. (Edit 3) In this function, there is no connection established with previous nodes. I hope, you take care of this in your caller function.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: Yeah I know about the newNode->next. The method that calls create node assigns the next one depending on where I call it, but because I have to call it multiple times I thought I'd do a separate method to create the basics of the node. Also, thank you I will remove the sizeof(char).

Comment: `strncpy()` is not a string-function. It's for null-padded buffers containing a sequence without embedded nulls. arely will you have reason to employ it, if ever at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likely candidate is this line:

```
struct node* temp = malloc (sizeof(struct node*));
```

Which creates enough space to store a *pointer to a node*, not to a node itself. Remove the `*` from the `sizeof` expression. Alternatively (and the way I would write this code), just don't use types in `sizeof` expressions if you can avoid it:

```
struct node *temp= malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

Other notes:

1. As mentioned by @VladFeinstein, use `strdup` instead of your `malloc`/`strlen`/`strncpy`/`\0` dance.

   ```
   temp->word = strdup(word);
   temp->id = strdup(id);
   ```
2. If you choose to not do that, notice that your order of operations seems confused in the `malloc` size expressions:

   ```
   temp->word = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(word) + 1);
   ```

   It's still correct, but only because `sizeof(char)` is `1`. I'd simply write:

   ```
   temp->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
   ```

   But if you're really set on leaving `sizeof(char)` in there, make sure you parenthesize the addition in the expression correctly.

Comment: Question, when I free the node, since I had to malloc the strings, do I have to free those individually?

Comment: Yes. Your `free` code will be something like: `free(node->word); free(node->document_id); free(node);`.

Answer (score 0):

We can look for an `off by 1` error in your code.

Alternatively, you can replace the use of `malloc`, `strncpy` and adding `\0` with *one* call to `strdup`.

Comment: Not likely the error, but it would tighten up this code nicely.